# Laravel 5 specify which field shows up in select form when using toArray()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a select form that lets the user select an option from a list of a model:

```
{!! Form::select('start_waypoint_id', array('0' => 'Select ...') + $waypointList->toArray(), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Right now the user sees the name field in the select drop down.  What I want to know is how do I change the field that the user sees when they are looking at the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pluck()` function as:

```
 $waypointList->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

It will return the array of `name`. You can use any other attribute in the pluck function which you want to show in the select.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you need to have and `ID` for the `value` of `select` tag, so you need to update your code to this:

```
$waypointList->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

As a bonus, I can tell you that, this is what I do in that scenario. I add the static method, called `toForm` (you can call it whatever you want, eg. `toSelect`) on my Eloquent model:

```
public static function toForm() {
    return (new static)->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
}
```

And in blade files i just use the following code:

```
ModelName::toForm();
```

IMHO, this way it's much more cleaner.